# Relative Image URL

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, file-upload

I am uploading the user image and store image in folder and their names in database

- Image upload done by angular
- Image store to folder and database done by dotnet core api

Both operations works fine ,but I am unable to display the stored Image in site.

SQL database store image url

[image]

To access this image in client side I am using following in angular

**Component.html file**

```
 <img [src]="createImgPath()" alt="profile picture" style="width:60px; height:60px;">
```

**.ts file**

```
 public createImgPath = () => {
debugger;
if(this.studentPriviewImage==null)
{
  return this.fallback;
}else{  
  console.log(data1);
  return environment.baseUrl+this.studentPriviewImage.filepath1; 
}

}
```

which returns **http://localhost:9529/Resources/Group/student_Photo/11/3/18/3_20220127002626AM.png**

If I directly try to access this in browser than I am getting following error

[image]

My Solution folder structure where image files are being stored.
[image]

Still not getting what is the problem. What is wrong in this approach.

Comment: Is http://localhost:9529 your server base url or Angular's one?

Comment: Where is the resources folder relative to the web root. Have you enabled static files -e.g. `UseStaticFiles()`  - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @yazantahhan its web api url

Comment: @SpruceMoose I have added the screenshot of my folder structure where I am storing images, please see the updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve files outside of web root,you need to add the following configuration in StartUp.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
    
   ...
   app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
   {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources")),
        RequestPath = "/Resources"
   });
```